# What options are out there for an Cross Domain WYSIWYG editor?

Tags: javascript, html, cross-domain, markdown, rich-text-editor

I'm writing a 3rd party API for use in client websites and I need a text editor with some basic functionality. It needs to be WYSIWYG as the end user is non technical. I've looked around and the smallest I've found for this functionality is 45Kb.

Has anyone implemented something like this cross domain? If not what is the smallest editor out there?

I've search and found many claiming to be lightweight but need to load 100Kb+.

Thanks,
Denis

Comment: What does cross-domain have to do with file size? Are you asking for the smallest one that supports Wysiwyg editing?

Comment: I want to be a good citizen and be as small a foot print on the page as possible. My initial research was finding large files needed for most of the options I came across, such as https://github.com/swilliams/jq-wysihat. I've since found http://nicedit.com/ which strips to 19Kb

Comment: Impressive, I', almost exclusively working with TinyMCE, so I guess 19kb sounding outrageous is not that surprising.

Comment: +1 for your own answer of NicEdit - basic, but nice and lightweight.

Answer (score 0):

I use the umbraco cms in most of my projects and its uses:

http://www.tinymce.com/

Works great across all browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the input. However "tiny"MCE is far from being tiny. It's a very large bit of software that I don't feel comfortable loading on someone else's page. If I recall correctly it is 80kb+. We do use it in my company on our own domain, however loading such a large tool across domain is far from optimum in my use case.

Answer (score 0):

I use Umbraco CMS.
This CMS implements `TinyMCE` but I prefere to use markdown instead of wysiwig editors.

Then I install `MarkdownDeep Editor`, with table support.
http://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/markdowndeep-editor